# Inserting news teaser inside FalMediaContainer template

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

Is it possible to insert {newsItem.teaser} into FalMediaContainer.html? Do I need to insert something more to fluid template to see on output news teaser?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course possible, however you need to change the `Detail.html` as well.

Please change the line

```
<f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaContainer" arguments="{media: newsItem.falMedia, settings:settings}" />
```

into

```
<f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaContainer" arguments="{newsItem:newsItem, media: newsItem.falMedia, settings:settings}" />
```

afterwards you can use any property of the `{newsItem}`also in the partial!